# Secure output stream

Tags: java, android, encryption

I have a simple question here:

I want to secure an OuputStream with encryption. I read about Java's CipherOutputStream. For me, this seems to be the best solution. It is not required to be the absolute safest of encryptions. But my question is:

**Does CipherOutputStream work with Android?** I want to send a username and a password via CipherOutputStream to a server. Is this an acceptable choice if I want some protection, whereas it may not be the Fort Knox of encryptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes android supports this `avax.crypto.CipherOutputStream`

http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/CipherOutputStream.html